# What does "?:" mean in PHP?

Tags: php, operators

While browsing the code of an open source PHP library I spotted this line:

```
$path = $path ?: $this->guessPackagePath();
```

This is not the ternary operator like it usually apprears. Would anyone explain what is going on in it?

Comment: I don't think it is dupe.

Comment: It's a ternary operator. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: For completeness, this special kind of ternary is called [Elvis operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a **[shortcut](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)** for

```
$path = $path ? $path : $this->guessPackagePath();
```

which comes from PHP 5.3

Comment: So what's going on in this unusual type of ternary op is that, if `$path` does not evaluate to `false` or an empty string, `$path` preserves its value, otherwise it's assigned to `$this->guessPackagePath()`, rite?

Comment: @DesmondHume Yes, that's right.

Comment: Note that if `$path` is not yet set, that it will raise a PHP warning.